# ‘registerExtension()’ has been renamed to ‘register()’

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift3

‘registerExtension()’ has been renamed to ‘register()’

I have a class method in objective - c : `+(void)registerExtension();`
When I invoke that method in my Objective C class it works fine. `[MyClass registerExtension];`

However, when I invoke the same in Swift I get the above mentioned error, even though it work.

**Why is it not allowing me to use the name.?? Any help is much appreciated.**

```
error: ‘registerExtension()’ has been renamed to ‘register()’
    MyClass.registerExtension()
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     register
```

__ObjC.MyClass:36:21: note: ‘registerExtension()’ was obsoleted in Swift 3
    open class func registerExtension()

Comment: It's been... almost 2 years since I actually used Swift 3, so take that into consideration. This sounds to me like it's *almost* related to something specific to Swift versions (and Swift 2 >> 3 was painful. BTW, which version of Xcode are you using? Certainly not Xcode 10.) One question of help - what happens if you rename your ObjC function `registerExtension` to something like `foo`?

Comment: I am using XCode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001). And working on swift 4.2 version of a sample app. Currently I am adding new features to the SDK I have developed, which is in Objective C. So I added a class method to achieve it. If I used other names like `+(void)testMyName;` , I can invoke it in swift like `MyClass.testMyname().` 
But I need to use `registerExtension` only as my method name.